# Two functions with the same name in JavaScript - how can this work?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, strict-mode

As far as I know, `function foo() { aaa(); }` is just `var foo = function(){ aaa() }` in JavaScript. So adding `function foo() { bbb(); }` should either overwrite the `foo` variable, or ignore the second definition - that's not the point. The point is that there should be one variable `foo`.

So, in this example the `me` variable should **not** be correctly resolved from inside the methods **and it is not in Explorer 8 :-)**. I came to this example by trying to wrap them into another closure where (`var`) `me` would be, but I was surprised that it's not necessary:

```javascript
    var foo = {
        bar1 : function me() {
            var index = 1;
            alert(me);
        },
        bar2 : function me() {
            var index = 2;
            alert(me);
        }    
    };

    foo.bar1(); // Shows the first one
    foo.bar2(); // Shows the second one
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W5dqy/5/

Comment: I have read your question 3 times and I still can't understand your problem

Comment: @Luis: It's a somewhat esoteric question about when and how function names are created and what scope they have. And yes, it's a bit tricky to follow. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry if the problem is in my English, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> AFAIK function foo() { aaa(); } is just var foo = function(){ aaa() } in JavaScript.

Not quite; they're *similar*, but also quite different. JavaScript has two different but related things: Function *declarations* (your first example there), and function *expressions* (your second, which you then assign to a variable). They happen at different times in the parsing cycle and have different effects.

This is a function *declaration*:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Function declarations are processed upon entry into the enclosing scope, before any step-by-step code is executed.

This is a function *expression* (specifically, an anonymous one):

```
var foo = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Function expressions are processed as part of the step-by-step code, at the point where they appear (just like any other expression).

Your quoted code is using a *named function expression*, which look like this:

```
var x = function foo() {
    // ...
};
```

(In your case it's within an object literal, so it's on the right-hand side of an `:` instead of an `=`, but it's still a named function expression.)

That's perfectly valid, ignoring implementation bugs (more in a moment). It creates a function with the name `foo`, *doesn't* put `foo` in the enclosing scope, and then assigns that function to the `x` variable (all of this happening when the expression is encountered in the step-by-step code). When I say it doesn't put `foo` in the enclosing scope, I mean exactly that:

```
var x = function foo() {
    alert(typeof foo); // alerts "function" (in compliant implementations)
};
alert(typeof foo);     // alerts "undefined" (in compliant implementations)
```

Note how that's different from the way function *declarations* work (where the function's name **is** added to the enclosing scope).

Named function expressions work on compliant implementations. Historically, there were bugs in implementations (early Safari, IE8 and earlier). Modern implementations get them right, including IE9 and up. (More here: [*Double take*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) and here: [*Named function expressions demystified*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).)

> So, in this example the `me` variable shoudl not be corectly resolved from inside the methods

Actually, it should be. A function's true name (the symbol between `function` and the opening parenthesis) is always in-scope within the function (whether the function is from a declaration or a named function expression).

**NOTE**: The below was written in 2011. With the advances in JavaScript since, I no longer feel the need to do things like the below unless I know I'm going to be dealing with IE8 (which is very rare these days).

Because of implementation bugs, I used to avoid named function expressions. You can do that in your example by just removing the `me` names, but [I prefer named functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), and so for what it's worth, here's how I used to write your object:

```
var foo = (function(){
    var publicSymbols = {};

    publicSymbols.bar1 = bar1_me;
    function bar1_me() {
        var index = 1;
        alert(bar1_me);
    }

    publicSymbols.bar2 = bar2_me;
    function bar2_me() {
        var index = 2;
        alert(bar2_me);
    }

    return publicSymbols;
})();
```

(Except I'd probably use a shorter name than `publicSymbols`.)

Here's how that gets processed:

1. An anonymous enclosing function is created when the `var foo = ...` line is encountered in the step-by-step code, and then it is called (because I have the `()` at the very end).
2. Upon entry into the execution context created by that anonymous function, the `bar1_me` and `bar2_me` function declarations are processed and those symbols are added to the scope inside that anonymous function (technically, to the *variable object* for the execution context).
3. The `publicSymbols` symbol is added to the scope inside the anonymous function. (More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html))
4. Step-by-step code begins by assigning `{}` to `publicSymbols`.
5. Step-by-step code continues with `publicSymbols.bar1 = bar1_me;` and `publicSymbols.bar2 = bar2_me;`, and finally `return publicSymbols;`
6. The anonymous function's result is assigned to `foo`.

These days, though, unless I'm writing code I know needs to support IE8 (sadly, as I write this in November 2015 it still has [significant global market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), but happily that share is plummetting), I don't worry about it. All modern JavaScript engines understand them just fine.

You can also write that like this:

```
var foo = (function(){
    return {
        bar1: bar1_me,
        bar2: bar2_me
    };

    function bar1_me() {
        var index = 1;
        alert(bar1_me);
    }

    function bar2_me() {
        var index = 2;
        alert(bar2_me);
    }
})();
```

...since those are function declarations, and thus are hoisted. I don't usually do it like that, as I find it easier to do maintenance on large structures if I do the declaration and the assignment to the property next to each other (or, if not writing for IE8, on the same line).

Comment: +1 for a well detailed answer. It's a known issue that named function expressions are handled incorrectly in IE/JScript.  They fixed the problem in IE9 when they wrote the whole new JavaScript engine based on ECMAScript 5th Edition.

Answer (score 3):

Both `me` lookups, are only visible/available **inside** the function expression.

Infact those two are *named function expressions*, and the ECMAscript specification tells us, that the name of an expression is not exposed to the such called `Variable object`.

---

Well I tried to put that only in a few words, but while trying to find the right words, this ends up in pretty deep chain of ECMAscript behavior. So, `function expression` are **not** stored in a `Variable` / `Activation Object`. (Would lead to the question, who those guys are...).

Short: Every time a function is called, a new `Context` is created. There is some "blackmagic" kind of guy that is called, `Activation object` which stores some stuff. For instance, the

- arguments of the function
- the [[Scope]]
- any variables created by `var`

For instance:

```
function foo(test, bar) {
    var hello = "world";

    function visible() {
    }

    (function ghost() {
    }());
}
```

The Activation Object for `foo` would look like:

- arguments: test, bar
- variables: hello (string), visible (function)
- [[Scope]]: (possible parent function-context), Global Object

`ghost` is not stored in the AO! it would just be accesssible under that name **within** the function itself. While `visible()` is a *function declaration* (or *function statement*) it is stored in the AO. This is because, a *function declaration* is evaluated when **parsing** and *function expression* is evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that `function()` has many different meanings and uses.

When I say

```
bar1 : function me() {
}
```

then that's 100% equivalent to

```
bar1 : function() {
}
```

i.e. the name doesn't matter when you use function to assign the variable `bar1`. Inside, `me` is assigned but as soon as the function definition is left (when you assign `bar2`), `me` is created again as a local variable for the function definition that is stored in `bar2`.

Comment: *"...then that's 100% equivalent to..."* It isn't **100%** the same (the former example gives the function a *name* and assigns that named function to `bar1`, the latter assigns an *anonymous* function to `bar1`), but it should be very nearly the same, yes. Unfortunately and importantly, though, the JavaScript interpreter with just about the biggest installed base (JScript in IE<=8) gets the first one completely wrong. :-)