# whats the difference between function foo(){} and foo = function(){}?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

are they the same? I've always wondered

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, they're not the same, although they do both result in a function you can call via the symbol `foo`. One is a function *declaration*, the other is a function *expression*. They are evaluated at different times, have different effects on the scope in which they're defined, and are legal in different places.

Quoting [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142286/two-functions-with-the-same-name-in-javascript-how-can-this-work/5142335#5142335) here (edited a bit for relevance), in case the other question were ever removed for some reason (and to save people following the link):

---

JavaScript has two different but related things: Function *declarations*, and function *expressions*. There are marked differences between them:

This is a function *declaration*:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Function declarations are evaluated upon entry into the enclosing scope, before any step-by-step code is executed. The function's name (`foo`) is added to the enclosing scope (technically, the *variable object* for the *execution context* the function is defined in).

This is a function *expression* (specifically, an anonymous one, like your quoted code):

```
var foo = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Function expressions are evaluated as part of the step-by-step code, at the point where they appear (just like any other expression). That one creates a function with no name, which it assigns to the `foo` variable.

Function expressions can also be *named* rather than anonymous. A named one looks like this:

```
var x = function foo() {  // Valid, but don't do it; see details below 
    // ...
};
```

A named function expression *should* be valid, according to the spec. It should create a function with the name `foo`, but *not* put `foo` in the enclosing scope, and then assign that function to the `x` variable (all of this happening when the expression is encountered in the step-by-step code). When I say it shouldn't put `foo` in the enclosing scope, I mean exactly that:

```
var x = function foo() {
    alert(typeof foo); // alerts "function" (in compliant implementations)
};
alert(typeof foo);     // alerts "undefined" (in compliant implementations)
```

Note how that's different from the way function *declarations* work (where the function's name **is** added to the enclosing scope).

Named function expressions work on compliant implementations, but there used to be several bugs in implementations in the wild, most especially Internet Explorer 8 and earlier (and some early versions of Safari). IE8 processes a named function expresssion *twice*: First as a function *declaration* (upon entry into the execution context), and then later as a function *expression*, generating two distinct functions in the process. (Really.)

More here: [*Double take*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142286/two-functions-with-the-same-name-in-javascript-how-can-this-work/5142335#5142335) and here: [*Named function expressions demystified*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

---

**NOTE:** The below was written in 2011. In 2015, function declarations in control blocks were added to the language as part of ECMAScript 2015. Their semantics vary depending on whether you're in strict or loose mode, and in loose mode if the environment is a web browser. And of course, on whether the environment you're using has correct support for the ES2015 definition for them. (To my surprise, as of this writing in July 2017, [Babel](https://babeljs.io) doesn't correctly transpile them, either.) Consequently, you can only reliably use function declarations within control-flow structures in specific situations, so it's still probably best, for now, to use function expressions instead.

<s>And finally, another difference between them is where they're legal. A function expression can appear anywhere an expression can appear (which is virtually anywhere). A function *declaration* can only appear at the top level of its enclosing scope, outside of any control-flow statements. So for instance, this is valid:</s>

```
function bar(x) {
    var foo;

    if (x) {
        foo = function() {  // Function expression...
            // Do X
        };
    }
    else {
        foo = function() {  // ...and therefore legal
            // Do Y
        };
    }
    foo();
}
```

...but this is not, and **does not** do what it looks like it does on most implementations:

```
function bar(x) {

    if (x) {
        function foo() {  // Function declaration -- INVALID
            // Do X
        }
    }
    else {
        function foo() {  // INVALID
            // Do Y
        }
    }
    foo();
}
```

And it makes perfect sense: Since the `foo` function declarations are evaluated upon entry into the `bar` function, before any step-by-step code is executed, the interpreter has no idea which `foo` to evaluate. This isn't a problem for expressions since they're done during the control-flow.

Since the syntax is invalid, implementations are free to do what they want. I've never met one that did what I would have expected, which is to throw a syntax error and fail. Instead, nearly all of them just ignore the control flow statements and do what they should do if there are two `foo` function declarations at the top level (which is use the second one; that's in the spec). So only the second `foo` is used. Firefox's SpiderMonkey is the standout, it seems to (effectively) convert them into expressions, and so which it uses depends on the value of `x`. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/oyiti5).

Comment: That.. was a fantasticly clear explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit outdated. The latest example with function declarations in control flow blocks works fine in Chrome (59).

Comment: @Shrike: Indeed, declarations in control blocks were codified in ECMAScript 2015. But the semantics of them vary depending on A) Whether you're using strict mode or loose mode, and B) In loose mode, whether the environment is a web browser. Consequently, I would recommend only using them in strict mode (if at all), where they are both consistent across environments (that support ES2015) and straightforward.

Comment: Agree, also it should be noted that in ES2015 strict mode block-level function declarations are visible only inside that block - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: @Shrike: Right. They're effectively converted into function expressions with `let`.

Answer (score 1):

I got an excellent explanation on this while asking very similar question: [Two functions with the same name in JavaScript - how can this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142286/two-functions-with-the-same-name-in-javascript-how-can-this-work)

Comment: I read the answer you linked to. Now I have to delete my own answer here. You learn something nwe every day..

Comment: Oh, hey, didn't see that you'd linked my earlier answer. Cheers!