# Difference between Javascript function declarations

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the following two examples?

```
setInterval(myFunc, 100);

function myFunc() { alert('asdf'); }
```

---

```
setInterval(myFunc, 100);

var myFunc = function myFunc() { alert('asdf'); }
```

Comment: If you would have just typed the title of your question into the StackOverflow search box, you would have gotten many answers, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403121/whats-the-difference-between-function-foo-and-foo-function

Comment: There is only one declaration above, the rest are assignments of function expressions.

Comment: `var myFunc = function myFunc() { alert('asdf'); }` => create a variable named myFunc. No wait, create a function named myFunc. Now set the variable to = myFunc the function. Now get rid of the function.

Answer (score 4):

According to ECMA standard, the first example is a function *statement* while the second is a function *expression*. According to Javascript a function statement counts as a definition, which means in the first example it is visible through the entire function (or script if it's not in a function). But in the second example, **var** myFunc will not have the value of **function** myFunc until the second line, and therefore setInterval will be passed `undefined`.

The only syntax difference between function statements and expressions is that statements are not included in are larger expression: eg: `(function foo() {})` is an expression, while `function foo() {}` is a statement.

NB: I believe old IE (pre 9?) treated all function expressions as definitions.

To expound on this answer, consider the following code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        alert(A);
        alert(B);
        function A() {return "A value";}
        var B = function B(){ return "B value";}

        alert(A);
        alert(B);
    </script>
```

this will alert (in order):

1. Function A()...
2. undefined
3. Function A()...
4. Function B()...

Comment: I expected the second example to fail on the `setInterval` part, for the same reason you gave. But when I tried it (in IE) it worked. Even if the `var myFunc` part is hoisted above, doesn't the actual assignment happen inline there after the `setInterval`? I'm confused.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think IE 9 standards mode fixed this, but checking up on this, it looks like IE has treated all function expressions as statements, so the second is equivalent to `function myFunc() {...} setInterval(...); var myFunc = myFunc;`

Comment: thanks. I thought it might be a weird IE thing, but IE(7) was all I had access to for a quick test. And (d'oh) I just saw the "NB" about IE at the end of your post that somehow I missed on first reading.

Comment: -1 for calling a FunctionDeclaration and "function statement". There is no such thing as a "function statement" in ECMAScript. There is a *FunctionDeclaration* and *FunctionExpression* described in ECMA-262 §13.

Comment: @RobG: Uhh, thanks for the clarification, it makes it easier to look up, but is that *really* a -1? A definition is (a specific type of) a statement, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Both samples are essentially doing the same thing.  In the second example, you can also use a named function with a different name or an unnamed function.

```
var myFunc = function myOtherName() { alert('asdf'); }
```

or

```
var myFunc = function() { alert('asdf'); }
```

They are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example:

```
> setInterval(myFunc, 100);
> 
> function myFunc() { alert('asdf'); }
```

The function declaration is processed before any code is executed, so *myFunc* exists as a local parameter when *setInterval* is called.

The second example:

```
> setInterval(myFunc, 100);
> 
> var myFunc = function myFunc() {
> alert('asdf'); }
```

<strike>works for exactly the same reason</strike>: *myFunc* is declared using *var* and therefore exists as a local variable when *setInterval* is called.

#### Edit

Ooops! It doesn't work. The value of *myFunc* is evaluated when *setTimeout* is called, and at that point *myFunc* hasn't bee assigned a value so an error results. Changing the value later doesn't affect the value held by *setTimeout*.

Finally, there is no such thing as a "function statement". ECMA-262 defines *FunctionDeclaration* and *FunctionExpression* in §13, there is no other kind of function.

Answer (score -1):

in the first example, you actually assign a newly created variable "myFunc" with a function data type. So, "myFunc" is the name of the variable, and function is the data type. The first one is the same as this:

```
var myFunc = function(){alert('asdf');}
```

I have never seen anything like in the second example. I dont know if its even a valid way to declare a function...

Comment: I just tested it (in firefox) and the second example is a function mechanism of declaring a function.  It seems to be declaring the function myFunc and then assigning a reference to that to the variable myFunc.  But this is executing in line, whereas the first example declares the function before linear code execution begins.