# Javascript binding event handler function by name

Tags: javascript, function, binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Why does this work...

```
$("#clickme").click( showAlert );

function showAlert() {
  alert( "Hiya" );
}
```

... but not this...?

```
$("#clickme").click( showAlert );

var showAlert = function() {
    alert( "Hello" );
}
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448567/difference-between-javascript-function-declarations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening due to [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).
In your first case, the code is interpreted as (notice how the function declaration is being evaluated first):

```
function showAlert() {
   alert( "Hiya" );
}
$("#clickme").click( showAlert );
```

And your second is interpreted as :

```
var showAlert;
$("#clickme").click( showAlert );

showAlert = function() {
   alert( "Hello" );
}
```

Since `showAlert` is a variable declaration and not a function declaration (notice the `var` keyword), the variable declaration is evaluated first, and by the time you bind the event handler, the `showAlert` variable is declared, but it holds the `undefined` value.

This is what hoisting does :  it *hoists* variable and function declarations to the top of the closure.
There are a couple of good resources on [hositing](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) out there, including [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting).

Comment: Here is another good article on [**JavaScript hoisting**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/). +1

Comment: thanks for reminding me about hoisting - I actually knew this already from using jslint but maybe because the var declaration was a function I didn't realise that it applied.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a `Function Declaration..`

The second is a `function Expression..`

**Function Declarations** are first read before any code is executed.

So the first case works . The second method does not work as that was not defined yet by the time the function is being assigned to it,..

So this will work

```
var showAlert = function() {
    alert( "Hello" );
}

$("#clickme").click( showAlert );
```

i.e, defining the function and then assigning the handler